# Get number of tweets per min for particular channel

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, twitter

I am using [pypi Twitter API](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI)

I need to call twitter API to get tweets of one channel after certain interval. I need tweet counts in that time period.

For ex. @NASA channel tweet counts of it every 5 mins.

I am looking at [search tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets) . Is this correct? But it does not give tweets count I think.

Comment: Why not count the amount of tweets on the initial load and then count them again each five minutes.  The difference is your count.

Comment: Ok Thanks! But which API is right to do this task. I got lost in their documentation can you help with this ?

Comment: @soupboy It sounds like you want to count tweets every 5 minutes as they are being tweeted, as opposed to every 5 minutes going back in time. Is that correct? If yes, you should use the Streaming API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use twitter's API.  I mean, right?

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline

That will get you the most 3200 recent tweets by a user. So unless those guys are literally more than like 10x /sec you should be good.

Hit the api every 5 minutes, including on page load.  Take the difference and there is your count.